# Can't pinpoint error origin using Chrome Developer Tools + Apps Script (Javascript error)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-developer-tools

I am trying to debug an error on my code, I am using Apps Script and I know my error is related to JavaScript. To be more exact, here:

```js
agendaColaboradores.append('<input class="elementoFormularioMovCob" type="time" id="movCobHoraEntradaES' + colaboradorTrim + '" name="movCobHoraEntrada' + colaboradorTrim + '"' + 'onchange="teste()"' + '>\r');
```

every time I edit the input, the `onchange` trigger works as expect. I know this because everytime I change the input value I get this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at userCodeAppPanel:1:40922)

With is useless since I can't check what is the code content. If i click `userCodeAppPanel:1:40922` it's just show me a blank script.

Nothing in this error seems to make sense:

```html
<input class="elementoFormularioMovCob" type="time" id="movCobHoraEntradaESAlexsandroLuizAlbani" name="movCobHoraEntradaAlexsandroLuizAlbani" onchange="teste()">
```

This is the result of the `.append`. A regular input element with no errors, it should just trigger `teste()` but I keep getting this content.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26518902/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
agendaColaboradores.append(`<input class="elementoFormularioMovCob" type="time" id="movCobHoraEntradaES${colaboradorTrim}" name="movCobHoraEntrada${colaboradorTrim}" onchange="teste();" />`);
```

Answer (score -1):

write debugger in the first line of taste function and then trigger it from frontend , it should stop execution in the first line of dev tools and from there you can step till the line you get error

Comment: like this?

  function teste() {

    debugger

    alert("ha");

  }

I still receiving the same output:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at userCodeAppPanel:1:40922)
change (async)
onKeyDown_ @ unknown

Comment: I can't even find my js scripts in the dev tools. Probaly is something apps scripts is messing with