# Use onEdit() to run client function in Google Apps Script web-app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script that I've published as a Web App.

It's all working fine - getting and updating data in a spreadsheet.

I'd like it so that if the spreadsheet is edited while the web app page is open in a browser it can reload the data (to get the changes.)

**How can I call a client-side javascript function from the onEdit() event handler?**

Or can I display a message to the user to tell them to reload the page. (Apparently I can't reload it for them: [Google apps script location.reload in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14674502) )

Would it need to be a simple event handler, or installed?

A hack-y way to do it would just be to reload the data every 20 minutes, but I'd like this to be used on mobile devices, so that might use up too much data!