# Sheets Prompt boxes Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a prompt walk through of entering text into specific columns of google sheet (i.e. a set of Mandatory fields)

Firstly I'm very inexperienced in coding, so my attempt so far has is based on my research online. I'm sure I have over complicated the script by repeating elements of the script.

I want it to be able to do the following

1 - Click on custom menu.
2 - Click on Add new Risk.
3 - Prompt box asks 4 sequence of questions - (As an example Name, Age, Address & Job).
4 - The responses are captured and put into the next available row in the sheet.
5 - The prompt box cancels the whole process by clicking the cross or the cancel button.

Problems to overcome

1 - So far I can get the script to ask the sequence of questions however it only pastes the last question response the next available row.

2 - I cant work out how to cancel the process, it just brings up a message and carries on the sequence of commands

3 - I need my responses to be fixed to specific columns i.e - Not all pasted into A2,B2,C2,D2. For example Name(A2), Age (G2), Address (H2) , Job (X2)

Any help would be much appreciated

```
    function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Risk Menu')
      .addItem('Add New Risk', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Add New Risk - Madantory Field 1/4',
      'Please enter your name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

     var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    range.setValue(text);
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('New risk cancelled');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }


    var result2 = ui.prompt(
      'Add New Risk - Mandatory Field 2/4',
      'Please enter your address:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);


      var button2 = result2.getSelectedButton();
  var text2 = result2.getResponseText();
  if (button2 == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    range.setValue(text2);
  } else if (button2 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('New risk cancelled');
  } else if (button2 == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
 }

  var result3 = ui.prompt(
      'Add New Risk - Mandatory Field 3/4',
      'Please enter your age:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

       var button3 = result3.getSelectedButton();
  var text3 = result3.getResponseText();
  if (button3 == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    range.setValue(text3);
  } else if (button3 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('New risk cancelled');
  } else if (button3 == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');

  }

  var result4 = ui.prompt(
      'Add New Risk - Mandatory Field 4/4',
      'Please enter your job role:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var button4 = result4.getSelectedButton();
  var text4 = result4.getResponseText();
  if (button4 == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    range.setValue(text4);
  } else if (button4 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('New risk cancelled.');
  } else if (button4 == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Separate your script logic into functions. Perhaps you can create a function that will take the title, prompt, and `Range`, and then return `true` or `false` if the next question should be asked...

Comment: Have you considered using a Google Form.  In a Spreadsheet look under Tools - > Form.  This way you can present a form to you users without them having to go directly to the spreadsheet.  They are easy to build and automatically update the spreadsheet with the info the use has input to the form.

Answer (score 0):

## A Custom Prompt Form with text input and a select

You can use this as a dialog or a webapp as the doGet() is included.  Theres just a couple of minor mods to run as a webapp.  One is identified in the script.html file with comments for webapp and/or dialog and the other is just to change the name of the Cancel button to Cancel/Reload.  And that's it.

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem("Show Dialog", 'showMyDialog')
  .addToUi()
}

function saveData(dObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var hA=rg.getValues()[0];
  var vA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    vA.push((dObj[hA[i]])?dObj[hA[i]]:'');//Column headers must agree with form names
  }
  sh.appendRow(vA);
  return;
}

function showMyDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TheHtml').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Form Data');
}

function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TheHtml').evaluate();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getSelectOptions() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  return vA;
}
```

TheHtml.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('resources') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= include('form') ?>
    <?!= include('script') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.html:

```
<script>    
     $(function(){  
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA) {
        $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        updateSelect(vA);
      })
      .getSelectOptions();
      });

     function updateSelect(vA,id){
      var id=id || 'sel1';
      var select = document.getElementById(id);
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][0],vA[i][1]);
      }
    }

    function getInputObject(obj) {
      var rObj={};
      for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++){
        //console.log('Name: %s Type: %s',obj[i].name,obj[i].type);
        if(obj[i].type=="text"){
          rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].value;
        }
        if(obj[i].type=="select-one"){
          rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].options[obj[i].selectedIndex].value;
        }
      }
      return rObj;
    }

    function processForm(obj){
      var fObj=getInputObject(obj);
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(fObj));
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
        var html='<br /><h1>Data Saved.</h1>';
        $(html).appendTo("body");
        google.script.host.close();
      })
      .saveData(fObj);
    }

    function cancel() {
      google.script.host.close();//as dailog
      //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url){window.open(url,'_top');}).getScriptURL();//as a webapp
      //https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754851/7215091
    }

    console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

form.html

```
<h3>Please enter Name, Age, Address and Job Title in the text areas adjacent to the text box descriptions.</h3>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();processForm(this);" >
  <br /><select name="Number" id="sel1"></select>
  <br /><input type="text" id="txt1" name="Name" /> Name
  <br /><input type="text" id="txt2" name="Age" /> Age
  <br /><input type="text" id="txt3" name="Address" /> Address
  <br /><input type="text" id="txt4" name="Job" /> Job
  <br /><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <br />
</form>
<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel/Reload" onClick="cancel();" />
```

css.html:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input[type="button"],input[type="text"]{margin:0 0 2px 0;}
</style>
```

resources.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The Dailog:

[image]

The Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: Working Great Cooper, just one thing, is it possible to leave the columns blank that are not included in the form. As when submitting it gives them a value of undefined.

Comment: I changed the saveData() function to accomplish that.